# Shift Solenoid Value causing misfires?

Tags: obd-ii, acura, misfire

I have a 2003 Acura TL-S.  I started it today (seemed fine yesterday) and it ran really rough.  I also hand a weird burning smell.

I attached my OBD2 reader, and got the following data:

```
P0300 - Random misfire
P0301 - misfire cylinder #1
P0303 - misfire cylinder #3
P0304 - misfire cylinder #4
P1399 - misfire any cylinder 
71-01
  1. Misfire cylinder #1
  2. Shift Solenoid value B malfunction
```

I have a few questions.  First, can the shift solenoid value malfunction cause the misfiring, and second, what is the shift solenoid value?  My initial Googling suggests its part of the transmission, but I wouldn't expect that to cause misfires.

The car has about 157K miles and I've been doing all services (the service reminder just came on yesterday actually so it was due anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the shift solenoid is the cause or just another symptom.  I'm *guessing* it's not the actual cause though.  Everything else could be explained by the car running too rich.  Perhaps a fuel pressure regulator failure or stuck fuel injector?  Bad batch of gas causing multiple injectors to stick open?  Maybe just a weak ignition coil?

Comment: The issue was an ignition coil.